# 3 columns, middle one with flexible width

Tags: css, positioning, css-float, css-tables

I'd like to have a layout that consist of three adjacent divs. Side divs have static width (it may change via javascript) and center div fills a remaining area. When the first div's size changes it affect only the center one. It is similar to table (with dynamic rendering) that consist of three columns.

Ok, but where is the problem.
The problem is that if I put floating-left div into the first column, and block div in the second and third one, block divs behave in a strange way. They are rendered in their column below floating div from the first column.

An example.
In the first and second column I have floating div, and block div in the third column. The block div is shifted down around the height of floating divs. Div in the center column is not shifted in his y position only that it has float left property.

I'd like to each of the three layouting divs to be independent on each other. I have no idea why elements in the third column floats div in first two columns (with float property).

CODE:

```
<div style="margin: auto; display: table; width: 260px;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100px;">

                <div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 50px;">COL1</div> 
            
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
        
                <div style="float: left; height: 50px;  width: 40px;">COL2</div>

            </div style="display: table-cell; width: 100px;">
            <div class="sideContainer">

                <div>COL3</div>

            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How do I make all layouting divs (columns) to be independent on each other? Any ideas?

Comment: You have an attribute on a close tab: `</div style=...>`

Comment: It's my mistake. The style on a close tab should be instead of 'class='sideContainer'; That's what is rendered in the result link

Comment: But, I think I understand why it works that way. So, for example: floating div in the center layouting div is the first child of it's parent. So if it has float attribut, but have nothing to float on his left, it floats her parent previous sibling (first layouting div).
To solve this I need to insert something (ie. div with width equal 0) in front of floating div. Or if I have two floating div, the first one must be float: none and display: inline.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do that by floating col1 and col3 to the left and to the right, with a fixed width.

Then add a left and right margin to col2 equal to the width of col1 and col3.

This gives you three columns; col1 and col3 having a fixed width and col2 filling the available width:

[image: col2's content box in blue, and its margins in yellow]
*(col2's content box in blue, and its margins in yellow)*

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='right'>
        col3
    </div>
    <div class='left'>
        col1
    </div>
    <div class='middle'>
        col2
    </div>
</div>



.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
.middle {
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/22YBU/

BTW if you need display: table, display: table-row and display: table-cell, use a table ;-)

Comment: ohhh yes, that's what I need. Point for you arnaud576875. Thanks.

Comment: The order of divs is important and not intuitive.

Comment: CSS floats are not intuitive :)

Comment: This order also works: left, right, middle. The important thing is that the floated divs come before the non-floated middle div.

Comment: Also, the margin on the .middle class doesn't seem to be necessary; the width will automatically contract to account for the floated divs.

Comment: The margin makes sure that the .middle won't be "line-wrapped" below .left and .right, in case the container isn't large enough (if that's the behavior you expect)

Comment: If we use this order, then the tab index will not go in the intuitive order (from left to right). Rather, the order will be right, left, middle. Is there a way around this?