# auto-width, percentages and fixed width resulting in DIV wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to have like a three columns page where the one in the middle has a dynamic width (window resize) AND a minimum one (`div #middle`: `min-width:400px;`).

Problem is that the third column is wrapping when I resize.

I know if I replace the `#middle div width:75%;` by `width:500px;` this would work and the right column won't wrap, but I won't have a dynamic width middle column anymore...

How an I solve this?

```css
#contentwraper {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 800px;
}

#left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("http://www.artetics.com/images/artfrontpageslideshow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  min-width: 128px;
  width: 12%;
  height: 128px;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("http://www.emoticonswallpapers.com/avatar/art/Test-Card.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  min-width: 128px;
  width: 12%;
  height: 128px;
}

.imagemiddle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("http://www.tradewindscientific.com/images/t_logo.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 25%;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentwraper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="imagemiddle"></div>
    <div class="imagemiddle"></div>
    <div class="imagemiddle"></div>
    <div class="imagemiddle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say the third column is wrapping is this due to its width being set to less than the minimum width?

Comment: please post this in a http://jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: If you want the right column to overflow on the right of the document when the page is too large (or the window not enough), the only solution is a table

Comment: @chriss : I don't know ecactly, I could instead of putting `width:12% `, `width:128px` it would wrap anyway
this the only way for this specific problem ? thanks

Comment: @arnaud576875  : http://jsfiddle.net/EDt6N/ thanks :) the problem is shown there now ! And I would rather not be using tables, is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the right column to overflow on the right of the document when the page is too large (or the window not enough), the only solution is a table.

Else, try this: [3 columns, middle one with flexible width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292021/3-columns-middle-one-with-flexible-width)

You can change #right's behavior by moving it after or before #left; or by setting overflow:hidden on #middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/3UAbN/1/

Comment: The result of #right before/after #left ; floating it to the right and overflow:hidden results in this : http://jsfiddle.net/EDt6N/2/ still not working. And the other post is kind of the result I want... but not working in my case :o

Comment: Almost thanks! I'd like it to extand as much as possible when resising the window so the #middle div would 'touch' the #right one. So how this would be possible without JS beeing implyied?

Comment: remove the float:left from #middle too (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292021/3-columns-middle-one-with-flexible-width )

Comment: Woops ! It seemed to work, but when applied to the real page, the right column was displayed under the middle, floating right. Reproduced in the fiddle (with a #middle having a greater height) : http://jsfiddle.net/EDt6N/4/
Having to remove the float seems weird too ?

Comment: it's not bellow, it's just that its height is greater than other columns, and the background is vertically centered http://jsfiddle.net/EDt6N/5/

Comment: Thanks for your time @arnaud576875, it's nicely fixed in the jsfiddle however I can't have it working in my code, I finally used an event listener on the resize to adapt the width of the middle collumn...!

Comment: check for differences in padding / margin / border, and DOCTYPE between the jsfiddle and your site