# Dynamic width of div between 2 other divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a design that should be:
Left container 200px
middle container dynamic
right container 200px

That means the midde container should be as much width as possible, specialy when the user resizes the browser.
I know what I describe is a perfect thing for a table, left and right td to width=200 and middle-td without width and the middle resizes perfectly to the scretch of the screen.
But to given reasons I have to use Div container here not a table.

So how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 columns, middle one with flexible width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292021/3-columns-middle-one-with-flexible-width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the calc() method to the middle container like :

```
width: calc(100% - 400px);
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L7amufw4/).

Comment: very simple and fast to use! Thanks! ATTENTION! calc(100%-400px) dont work, only calc(100% - 400px) works! Spaces are importent!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table` to replicate table behaviour with divs like so:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  width: 200px;
}
.right {
   width: 200px;
}
```

[Demo @ CodePen](http://codepen.io/redclov3r/pen/iJDBG)

Answer (score 0):

Give the middle one `margin: 0 200px;`

The left one: `margin-right: -200px;`

The right one: `margin-left: -200px;`

And let them float. Make sure to set the width of the outer ones to 200px aswell.

Answer (score 0):

First you define all the `divs` as `display: inline-block` and then you style the left and right `divs` with a width of 200px and let them float. Then set the container width to the desired width.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='right'>
        col3
    </div>
    <div class='left'>
        col1
    </div>
    <div class='middle'>
        col2
    </div>
</div>
```

Then give the middle one `margin: 0 200px;`

The left one: `margin-right: -200px;`

The right one: `margin-left: -200px;`